# How to remove whitespace in textbutton in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, android-widget, removing-whitespace

I'm very new to flutter and I have been practicing the basics. I just have one problem, which is the extra white space in my TextButton widget when the modal pops out.

This is my current code

```
                                                    TextButton(
                                                              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                                                  backgroundColor:
                                                                      Colors
                                                                          .blue,
                                                                  padding:
                                                                      EdgeInsets
                                                                          .zero,
                                                                  tapTargetSize:
                                                                      MaterialTapTargetSize
                                                                          .shrinkWrap,
                                                                  alignment:
                                                                      Alignment
                                                                          .centerLeft),
                                                              onPressed:
                                                                  () {},
                                                              child:
                                                                  Padding(
                                                                padding: const EdgeInsets
                                                                        .symmetric(
                                                                    horizontal:
                                                                        12,
                                                                    vertical:
                                                                        0),
                                                                child: Text(
                                                                  'Hello / SIGN NOW',
                                                                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                                                      fontSize:
                                                                          10,
                                                                      color: CupertinoColors
                                                                          .white,
                                                                      fontWeight: FontWeight
                                                                          .w500,
                                                                      letterSpacing:
                                                                          0.4,
                                                                      wordSpacing:
                                                                          2),
                                                                ),
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
```

This the result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlucD.png)

I tried adding more horizontal padding and white space also extends.
I tried also wrapping it to to container widget and set margin to EdgeInsets.zero, nothing changes.

Please help this is my first ticket in my development journey. Any advice and resource is appriciated.

Comment: the code you are share with us is fine, can you add your full code?

Comment: your TextButton is good (https://dartpad.dev/?id=e75b493dae1287757c5e1d77a0dc73f1).. Can you share please the parent widget

Comment: I think u are warping this code with a card, please share ur full code

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the widget is not the problem, so I did some digging and found out it wraps in a container with no width. I fixed it. Thank you for reviewing!